# Log4Net Outlook config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, log4net

I have reviewed the topics related to this topic. But I could not find the answer.
I use the following code to send errors via Log4Net as "Error".
Where am I going to make the mistake?

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender,log4net">
  <from value="from@outlook.com" />
  <to value="to@gmail.com" />
  <subject value="ErrorLogmessage" />
  <smtpHost value="smtp-mail.outlook.com" />
  <authentication value="Basic" />
  <port value="587" />
  <username value="from@outlook.com" />
  <password value="realpassword" />
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator,log4net">
    <threshold value="ERROR"></threshold>
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ERROR"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
</root>
```

Comment: What are your symptoms? Any errors/exceptions from the logging code? Can you use basic C# to email using those SMPT details successfully? If you use another appender (`FileAppender` for example) are errors logged successfully?

Comment: With Basic C # I can successfully send SMTP mail. I did not receive any errors in FileAppender. I can not send mail with the code I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the property:

```
<enableSsl value="true"/>
```

Make sure you are using the latest log4net version.

Also enable internal debugging if it fails. That will give you more insights in what is going on in log4net and why it fails.

[log4net faq => enable internal debugging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)